# Modelling contests in Rails, a good time for postgres array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I'm about to build a contest functionality on my site. I have questions regarding modeling and the use of postgresql array datatype and if this would be the right use for it.

**Specs:**

> My app does have some users but the I don't expect the contest to be under huge stress user/entries-wise. App is run using ruby 2.1.3, rails 4.1.6 and postgresql 9.3.5.

**My thoughts:**

The different contest will be similar to each other in terms of predictions. Each contest will have a number of players/teams (these will differ over each contest). The user will be asked to predict which teams/players finish 1st place, 2nd place, 3-4th place, 4-8th place.

With this mindset I thought I could skip to put teams/players into an own modes and instead put the teams/players available to chose from in an array inside the contest table.

I'm also thinking I could put the placement predictions inside the entries table, like: 1st, 2nd, 3-4th(array), 5-8th(array) and the same goes with results into the contest table.

**Relations looking like this:**

> Contest
>
> - has many :entries
>
> User
>
> - has many :entries
>
> Entry
>
> - belongs_to :contest
> - belongs_to :user

**I would query the arrays when:**

*1) Entries - new: The user needs to see which teams are available when making their predictions in the form.*

*2) Contest - edit: I need to update the contest with the teams placements.*

*3) Entries - update: Automatic grading of the entries, comparing the entry predictions with the contests answers/results.*

Would this be a good use of postgresql array type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgreq's `JSONB` allows indexing, which makes it more efficient than the non-indexed `JSON` type and theoretically allows for non-relational storage in a relational database.

However, in your specific case, I would stay away from the array type. It's a personal opinion and I don't think Rails' ORMs are friendly enough just yet for querying complex `JSONB`, especially when you decide to add more complex features.

As a rule of thumb, I would use the `JSONB` type for caching and simple value storage (ie. list of tags or keywords. Yes, you can think of your users as an array but again, if you want to change something or adding extra information, you'll end up modifying this and it will be hard to deal with) but not on tables that have complex relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Just to clarify, my users got an own model. The contests I'm creating are tipster competitions. So its more like a user joins a contest through their entry and then predics the top8 of say, the european championship in soccer.

Comment: Yes, I would still use a relational approach in here because later on, you'll want to get some stats about your users/contests, create other tables and join on them, etc...